How do I forget a WiFi network when the "Forget This Network…" button is grayed out?
Problem:

I have a WiFi network I'd like to forget.

I have admin rights on the mac (Sonoma, MacBook).

I can and have connected to this network.

In the Wi-Fi control panel, there is no lock/unlock button.

In the "Network Settings…" popup from the (…) menu in the Wi-Fi control pane, the "Forget This Network…" option is grayed out.

In the "Advanced…" dialog at the bottom of the Wi-Fi control panel,

No actions are set to "Require admin…";
Under "Known Networks", all WiFi networks can be removed except this one.



Question:
How do I forget this WiFi network?
Why this is not an exact duplicate:
This question is not an exact duplicate of the linked question, because it pertains to the specific situation where a user can remove a wifi network, but the System Settings GUI is presenting false and misleading information that implies it is not possible.

Although the network SSID appears non-removable in the Wi-Fi control panel GUI, if you have admin rights you can remove it using the command line.
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en0 GOODBYE_NETWORK_NAME

